# write method of Zipfile library python not working in google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

i'm trying create zip files in bucket of google cloud storage, but the write method of library Zipfile is not working.
I can create the zip file, but can't add the file using de write method.
The error show is: **[Errno 2] No such file or directory:**
But the file exists.

Can someone help me?
Below an example of my code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import google.auth
import gcsfs
import zipfile

PROJECT_ID = <id_project>
BUCKET = <name_bucket>
PATH_FILE = 'gs://{BUCKET}/folder/'
FILE_NAME = 'file.csv'
NAME_FILE_ZIP = 'file.zip'

#Prepare Bucket
gcs = storage.Client(PROJECT_ID)
bucket_target = gcs.get_bucket(BUCKET)

#Create ZIP file
credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=PROJECT_ID, token=credentials)
f = fs.open(PATH_FILE + NAME_FILE_ZIP,'w')
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f,'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

zip.write(PATH_FILE + FILE_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have an other solution, which depends on streaming the Data out to the Bucket.

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
source_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(<BUCKETNAME>)
archive = io.BytesIO()
....
with ZipFile(archive, 'w') as zip:
    for file in filterBlobs:
        data = source_bucket.blob(<PATH_FILE>).download_as_string()
        zip.writestr(file.split("/")[-1],data)
    zip.close()
    archive.seek(0)
....
blob = storage.Blob(<NAMEOFZIP>'.zip', source_bucket)
blob.upload_from_file(archive, content_type='application/zip')
```

Your problem might be an error which occurs because you handle the File System wrong. In your case python is trying to find the file locally.